# Azure Logic Apps: How to use variables in a dynamic query?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, dynamicquery

Trying to add values from the JSON Parser into a dynamic Oracle query but always shows up as blank/empty.

Same results trying to use the formal parameters and declaring them within the Oracle query as well.

Is this possible?

Service Bus trigger. Message comes in and goes into the "For each message" loop. It then gets parsed in the "Parse JSON Message" and when I try to use the dynamic content from that in an Oracle query (e.g. @body('Parse_JSON_Message')?['contentData']?['dynamicValue']), they always show up as nothing/blank.

I can use this same reference later (again @body('Parse_JSON_Message')?['contentData']?['dynamicValue']) with no issues but it always ends up blank in the query.

Even using formal parameterized key values shows the @body('Parse_JSON_Message')?['contentData']?['dynamicValue']) to be NULL.

So my queries are coded as:

```
SELECT thisValue
WHERE columnName = @body('Parse_JSON_Message')?['contentData']?['dynamicValue'] (have also tried @{body('Parse_JSON_Message')?['contentData']?['dynamicValue']})
```

But are coming out as:

```
SELECT thisValue
WHERE columnName =
```

...with no result obviously.

This query does work if I hard code the value.

If I use dynamic values in my output (where I'm mapping data), it works fine. So how should I correctly dynamic values in this Oracle query?

Comment: We need more info if you want a proper answer. Can you provide elements of the flow in screenshots or even the json definition for the logicapp? Any detail is better than none but provide enough so we can actually help because right now, an educated answer to your question is **yes**.

Comment: Service Bus trigger. Message comes in and goes into the "For each message" loop. It then gets parsed in the "Parse JSON Message" and when I try to use the dynamic content from that in an Oracle query (e.g. @body('Parse_JSON_Message')?['contentData']?['dynamicValue']), they always show up as nothing/blank.


I can use this same reference later (again @body('Parse_JSON_Message')?['contentData']?['dynamicValue']) with no issues but it always ends up blank in the query.

Comment: Add it to the question please including screenshots and json definitions.

Comment: … and your source json looks like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Neve used the task exactly, but all DB-related tasks in the Logic Apps can create parameters. You should create query with parameters like usually in Oracle, then go out of the task in Logic App, then Logic App will add parameters to the task and you will be able to use as usual.